Showing All Messages Plugin [id: 'com.android.library'] was not found in any of the following sources: error when installing the Pod in iOS
I'm updating our Kotlin multi platform project to the latest version of kotlin, Gradle and various plugin, which basically is is just our API interface and we use in our native mobile app projects.
As for the PlayStore requirements we had bump the compile version to 34, so the Android guy updated kotlin to version 1.9.10 plus a few changes in the code
object Versions {
    const val iosTestTask = false
    const val foo = "8.8.8"
    const val kotlin = "1.9.10"

    // Gradle
    const val androidGradlePlugin = "7.2.2"
    const val gradle = "gradle-7.4.1-bin"

    // Android
    const val compileSdk = 34
    const val minSdk = 23
    const val targetSdk = compileSdk

    // You can also use this to specify versions for dependencies. Having consistent
    // versions between modules can avoid behavior conflicts.
    const val sqldelight = "1.5.2" // https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/2790
    const val settings = "0.9"
    // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines
    const val coroutines = "1.6.1-native-mt"
    const val ktor = "1.6.8" // openapi-gen is still not compliant with ktor 2.0... :'(
    const val openapigen = "5.3.0"
    //
    const val crashkios = "0.6.0"
}

The problem is that, dough the build of the multi platform project succeeds, after running pod install the iOS project build fails with the error:

Showing All Messages
* What went wrong:

Plugin [id: 'com.android.library'] was not found in any of the following sources:



- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)

- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)

- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)


I went a step further and updated to the latest Kotlin, Gradle and gradle-plugin and updated the code to use @OptIn(kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalNativeApi::class) where the compiler was pointing, so it does compile again with no errors but still Xcode build fails showing the same error on the multiplatform module.
Actual used versions:
object Versions {
    const val iosTestTask = false
    const val foo = "8.8.8"
    const val kotlin = "1.9.20"

    // Gradle
    const val androidGradlePlugin = "8.5.1"
    const val gradle = "gradle-8.9-bin"

    // Android
    const val compileSdk = 34
    const val minSdk = 23
    const val targetSdk = compileSdk

    // You can also use this to specify versions for dependencies. Having consistent
    // versions between modules can avoid behavior conflicts.
    const val sqldelight = "1.5.2" // https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/2790
    const val settings = "0.9"
    // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines
    const val coroutines = "1.6.1-native-mt"
    const val ktor = "2.0.0"
    const val openapigen = "6.2.1"
    const val crashkios = "0.6.0"
}

The latest iOS working setup is with these versions:
object Versions {
    const val iosTestTask = false
    const val foo = "8.8.8"
    const val kotlin = "1.7.10"

    // Gradle
    const val androidGradlePlugin = "7.2.2"
    const val gradle = "gradle-7.4.1-bin"

    // Android
    const val compileSdk = 33
    const val minSdk = 23
    const val targetSdk = compileSdk

    // You can also use this to specify versions for dependencies. Having consistent
    // versions between modules can avoid behavior conflicts.
    const val sqldelight = "1.5.2" // https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/2790
    const val settings = "0.9"
    // https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines
    const val coroutines = "1.6.1-native-mt"
    const val ktor = "1.6.8" // openapi-gen is still not compliant with ktor 2.0... :'(
    const val openapigen = "5.3.0"
    //
    const val crashkios = "0.6.0"
}

I also noticed a behavior that I can't explain.
In  the module build.gradle.kts if I reference the plugin versions from an object as it was before the updates the error in Xcode is

Showing All Messages
Script compilation errors:



  Line 26:     id("com.squareup.sqldelight") version Versions.sqldelight

                                                     ^ Unresolved reference: Versions



  Line 27:     kotlin("plugin.serialization") version Versions.kotlin apply true

                                                      ^ Unresolved reference: Versions



  Line 28:     id("org.openapi.generator") version Versions.openapigen

                                                   ^ Unresolved reference: Versions


but it doesn't complain about id: 'com.android.library':
plugins {
    // https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library
    id("com.android.library")
//    id("com.android.library") version "8.5.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform")
    // https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/COCOAPODS.md
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods")

    // referencing the Versions in Dependencies.kt results in
    // Unresolved reference: Versions
//    id("com.squareup.sqldelight") version Versions.sqldelight
//    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version Versions.kotlin apply true
//    id("org.openapi.generator") version Versions.openapigen


    // specifying versions directly works, leaving only the
    // id("com.android.library") not found error

    id("com.squareup.sqldelight") version "1.5.2"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.10" apply true
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "6.2.1"

}

I'm not able to find a solution to the issue. Can you spot what's wrong with setup?
Many thanks
Here's more setup snippets from the project build.gradle.kts:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
//        maven ( url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" )
//        maven {
//            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
//        }
        maven (url = "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${Versions.androidGradlePlugin}")
        classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${Versions.kotlin}")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        // classpath ("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:${Versions.sqldelight}")
        // classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:${Versions.kotlin}")
        // classpath ("org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:${Versions.openapigen}")
    }
}

